# How to hide the current JFrameForm and launch a new JFrameForm

Tags: java, swing

Cannot hide a JFrameForm in netbeans project. I tried

```
Jframe1 p = new Jframe1();
p.setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false);
```

This didn't worked.
i wanted to launch a new jframe form when a selection is being made in the jtable and hide the current one in which the selection is being made.
Please explain me the issue and help me with the easiest way out. i am new to java programming.

My Code -

```
ListSelectionModel rowSM = jTable1.getSelectionModel();

rowSM.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
        int selectedRow = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
        int k = selectedRow + 1;

        DefaultTableModel tma = (DefaultTableModel) Select_Album.jTable1.getModel();
           ResultSet rst=null;

        try
        {
            Connection conn=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/music", "root","root");
            Statement stmt1=(Statement) conn.createStatement();
            String sql1="select * from album where genreid="+k+" ;    "; 
            rst =stmt1.executeQuery(sql1);
            rst.first();

            this.setVisible(false); //error- cannot find symbol method :
                                      //setVisible(boolean) 



            Select_song p = new Select_song();
            p.setVisible(true);

            do
            {
                tma.addRow(new Object[] {rst.getInt("id"),rst.getInt("artistid"),rst.getString("name"), rst.getInt("genreid")}); 
            }while (rst.next());

            conn.close();
            stmt1.close();

        }
        catch(Exception o) 
        {
            System.out.println(o.getMessage());
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Don't.  Use a `CardLayout` or `JTabbedPane` and limit the number of frames you projects creates.  See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for more details

Comment: //error in this line. ?  What error? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: please help me to use create the following if the above is not correct.    i wanted ti get details from mysql table and paste it in a jframe form using table. i know how to make a connection using to mysql. now i got the data and i wanted to select a column and get the minimum selected index. i used this number to select the line no and connected another frame and a table in my database and run a query in mysql using that minimum selected index. when my new activity gets launched i wanted to close the old  form. i am not able to do that. please help ..!

Comment: the error - cannot find symbol method : setVisible(boolean)